# How to set in-text citations in italic?

Tags: biblatex, citing, italic, authoryear

I'm using the authoryear-comp citestyle of biblatex and I'd like the author and year to appear in italics in in-text citations. After some research, I've found the following command, but it only italicizes the author:

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}

Does anyone know, on the basis of the following example, how to get the year italicized as well?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Knu86,
        author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
```

Many thanks for having a look at this and best wishes,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to make citation italic is to inject a `\mkbibemph` into the wrapper code of `\DeclareCiteCommand` for the relevant `\...cite` commands you want to be in italic.

You can find the `\DeclareCiteCommand` declarations in `<citestyle>.cbx` (in your case `authoryear-comp.cbx`). Note that these definitions can differ between styles, so you need to make sure you have got the correct ones.

In the example we show how to make `\cite`/`\cite*` and `\parencite`/`\parencite*` italic. The original definitions can be found in [`authoryear-comp.cbx`, ll. 160-190 in v3.18b](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/81a5e01777e0b3a79a4d12a3b790f233a9922c3d/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-comp.cbx#L160-L190): For `\cite` we just add `\mkbibemph` as wrapper command (because `\cite` does not have a wrapper). For `\parencite` we combine `\mkbibemph` with the wrapper `\mkbibparens` (change the order of `\mkbibemph` and `\mkbibparens` in `\mkbibemphparens` to make the parentheses italic too).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibemph]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}[\mkbibemph]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand*{\mkbibemphparens}[1]{\mkbibparens{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibemphparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibemphparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite{nussbaum}
dolor \cite{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor Worman 2002 [the citation labels are in italics]]

Comment: Dear moewe, I'm very impressed!! Thank you very much for your answer - it perfectly works exactly the way you put it. Have a wonderful day and thanks again.