# How to set citations with \textcite in italic

Tags: biblatex, citing, italic, authoryear

I use `biblatex` and the style `authoryear`. I use the command `\textcite` to make in-text citations.
Currently `\textcite` outputs something like:

[image]

But I'd like to have it in italic (including parentheses), like this:

[image]

I'm aware of this similar post [How to set in-text citations in italic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609460/how-to-set-in-text-citations-in-italic) However it focuses on `\cite` and `\parencite`, but not `\textcite`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    natbib=true, 
    bibencoding=utf8,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyt, 
    maxcitenames=2, 
    giveninits=true, 
    uniquename=init]{biblatex}

% Because of the use of the french option of babel with biblatex, all names are in uppercase. This revert to lowercase except the first letter of the names.
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{cicero}

\printbibliography[
    title={Bibliographie},
]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in the linked Q&A. Copy the definition of `\textcite` from your style (in this case [`authoryear.cbx`, ll. 126-137 in v3.18b](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/868b79fecb7998742eae53d2f81bb637453ceaf7/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx#L126-L137)) and add a `\mkbibemph` to the wrapper code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2, 
  giveninits=true, 
  uniquename=init,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\mkbibemph]
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{cicero}

\printbibliography[
  title={Bibliographie},
]
\end{document}
```

[image: "Cicero (1995)" in italics]

Do note that the definition of `\textcite` depends on the style. `\textcite`'s implementation is quite a bit more complex in more complex styles. The general approach will still work, but it might need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: That works as intended, thank you very much moewe!